# swift take member from array if found in another array

Tags: swift

I fetch a list of users from the database with their details and I also fetch  a list of blocked userID's from the database

I just want to subtract the list of blocked user from the users array and and then load the screen so blocked user don't show up

I have an array of userId's called
"UsersBlockingCurrentUserArray"

I am aiming for;   users - UsersBlockingCurrentUserArray =  newarray 
load newarray

```
func fetchUsers(){
    //fetch users code get "user"
    self.users.append(user)
    self.users.sort(by: { (p1, p2) -> Bool in
        return p1.distanceFrom.compare(p2.distanceFrom) == .orderedAscending
    })
    self.collectionView?.reloadData()           
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is create `Set` of the array which has all users and subtract the other sequence from it. Example is as follows:

```
let allUsersSet = Set(users)

let newArray = Array(allUsersSet.subtracting(UsersBlockingCurrentUserArray))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` method in your users array:

```
newArray = userArray.filter { (user) -> Bool in
    !UsersBlockingCurrentUserArray.contains(user.id)
}
```